# How to specify Multiple conditions in Java Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a code which requires me to get user details from a mongo database collection

Following is one of the field in my Users collection

```
"emailSettings" : {
    "flag1" : true,
    "flag2" : true,
    "flag3" : true,
},
```

I'm parsing the Mongo collection from my java program using the `BasicDB` object and I would want to get all the entries which satisfy the `emailSettings.flag1 =true` and `emailSettings.flag2 = true`.

When I use `BasicDBObject` to do this, I'm able to get entries satisfying only one of the conditions.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

In Mongo query parts are combined with 'and' operator by default. So simply doing this

```
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("emailSettings.flag1", true).add("emailSettings.flag2", true).get();
```

should give you expected result.

Comment: If I also need to check for a condition in the above statement, For Example: I need to check whether emailsettings.email field has "@gmail.com", and I need  to check whether there is a substring "test.com" in the email id field

Comment: @Raja you can use regexp for that: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions